# Difference between Url.Action and Html.RenderActionLink and Html.RenderAction

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Whats the difference between `Url.Action` and `Html.RenderActionLink` in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the one that starts with Url only gives you the URL. the Html.RenderActionLink renders the actual HTML for a link